# How do I get the names of all currently available IBMQ devices?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

How do I get the names of all currently available IBMQ devices?

Comment: To those attempting close vote, what "details" or "clarity" do you think could be added? The question is clear, and that's why it got 4 answers.

Comment: @user1271772 I believe OP is referring `backends` as IBMQ devices. Backends are organised by `providers` which have the form `hub/group/project`. I wish some answers could cover this as well for clarity for beginners.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar I find your comment less clear than the original question.

Comment: @user1271772 Check this [provider](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/provider/). There is a depiction of what I just said viz., `The combination of hub/group/project is called a provider`.

Comment: You can write about that in an answer if you want, but what you've sent me is certainly new in that it didn't exist in the early days of the IBM Quantum Experience. The question on which we're commenting is 1.5 years old. It was clear enough at the time to get multiple decent answers. My comment was just saying that the question shouldn't be closed, and I'm glad that it wasn't.

Answer (score 9):

You can see the backends you can access directly on the [IBM Quantum tools](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com) by going on the top left corner of the page, click and then go to *Quantum Services*, and click on "Yours".

Now, via Qiskit, you can do this, for example to access the open provider and get the backend `ibmq_athens`:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
print(provider.backends())
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_athens')
```

Hope this helps, tell me if you need more details on something! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have only one provider (which is the most common case) you can print all your backend names like this:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
print([backend.name() for backend in IBMQ.providers()[0].backends()])
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!